# MATLAB Engine API for Python: changing parameters of the running simulation

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, matlab-engine

I am using the `MATLAB Engine API for Python`. I have a shared engine in a Python script and then another Python script connected to this shared engine. I would like to ask whether it is possible to change the parameter of the running simulation from Simulink using `set_param` command. It looks like my following solution does not work. The `set_param` command in the 2nd script is waiting until `sim()` command from the 1st script is finished. Thanks in advance.

1st script:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.eval("matlab.engine.shareEngine('my_sim123')")
eng.eval("load_system('scheme123')",nargout=0)
eng.eval("sim('scheme123')")
```

2nd script:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab('my_sim123')
eng.eval("set_param('scheme123/PID', 'P', '15')",nargout=0)
```

**UPDATE:** I tried to use `set_param('scheme123', 'SimulationCommand','Start')` instead, but the following error occured: "You cannot use set_param to run a simulation in a MATLAB session that does not have a display." Is there any other way to change the parameter of the running sumulation with no display?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue with the Python API.  The `sim` command is blocking - even when used from within MATLAB itself.

To over come this you need to start the simulation using

```
set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','Start')
```

That will run the simulation to completion.  If you need/want to stop it prematurely then use

```
set_param(gcs,'SimulationCommand','Stop')
```

Comment: I tried to use `eng.set_param('scheme123', 'SimulationCommand','Start',nargout=0)` instead, but the following error occured: "You cannot use set_param to run a simulation in a MATLAB session that does not have a display." Is there any other way to change the parameter of the running sumulation with no display?

Comment: You'll need to start the MATLAB engine with the desktop open: `matlab.engine.start_matlab('-desktop')`.  I don't believe you have any other options.  You can also use `-minimize` and `-nosplash` to avoid the nuicanse of the desktop being displayed.